# iTextSharp controller The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, itext

Good day, I've read an article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3 , and try to use this in my test project, and everything work perfect. But when I add this to my main project I've got an error

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /TextSharp

And I dont know where I have a mistake. Any ideas?

**Added**

**Controller**

```
public class TextSharpController : PdfViewController
{
    private UniversityRepository repo = new UniversityRepository();

    //
    // GET: /TextSharp/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = repo.GetStudents().ToList();
        return this.ViewPdf("Test report", "Index", model, 39);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Project.Web.Models.Entities.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Student</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApplicationNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ApplicationNumber)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PersonalCode)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersonalCode)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nationality)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nationality)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.StudentId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

**Global.asax**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "TextSharp",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "TextSharp", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

    }

    protected void Application_Start() {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        //FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        //Database.SetInitializer<UniversityContext>(new UniversityInitializer());

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        //RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        //RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post full code, it is not clear

Comment: Its seem to be that you link an action that doesnt exist, its obvious, but are you sure you generate or use the correct URL?